# how to solve the logarithmic equation which has both n and logn

Tags: logarithms

How to solve this logarithmic equation? $8n^2 = 64n\log n$, ($\log n$ here is base 2)
I have tried to convert it to $n-8\log n = 0$, but how to solve the latest?

Comment: Please use MathJax, see [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have any solutions using elementary functions. But, using the [Lambert W function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), we get: $$n = -\frac {8}{\ln 2} \operatorname{W} \left (-\frac {\ln 2}{8} \right)$$ and $$n = -\frac {8}{\ln 2} \operatorname{W}_{-1} \left (-\frac {\ln 2}{8} \right)$$

Comment: This is fine but there are two solutions.

Comment: Sorry, @ClaudeLeibovici sir.

Comment: Don't be sorry for anything !

Comment: In case anybody has doubts concerning the usefulness of those expressions: Wolfram Alpha happily converts them into numbers: like [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-8%2Flog(2)*LambertW%5B-1,-log(2)%2F8%5D)

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) sorry I don't know about Lambert function, will it allow me to get the final numeric value for n? e.g. n = 42
Just found some solutions to my exercise, but not sure which method is good to use
http://atekihcan.github.io/CLRS/E01.02-02/

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use Lambert function, consider that you look for the zero's of $$f(x)=x-8\log_2(x)$$ The first derivative
$$f'(x)=1-\frac{8}{x \log (2)}$$ cancels for $x_*=\frac{8}{\log (2)}$ and 
$$f(x_*)=\frac{8-8 \log \left(\frac{8}{\log (2)}\right)}{\log (2)}\approx -16.6886$$ The second derivative test shows that this corresponds to a minimum. So, there are two roots to the equation.

If you plot the function, you will see that the roots are close to $1$ and $40$. So, start Newton method and below are given the iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.000000000 \\
 1 & 1.094862617 \\
 2 & 1.099983771 \\
 3 & 1.099997030
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 40.00000000 \\
 1 & 43.61991000 \\
 2 & 43.55927562 \\
 3 & 43.55926044
\end{array}
\right)$$